# multiple commands in local-exec provisioner terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to achieve something inside terraform local-exec provisioner. So it looks something like this currently

```
resource null_resource ledger_summary_backup {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
     BackupArn=`aws dynamodb create-backup --table-name ${var.environment_id}-AccountService-LedgerSummary --backup-name ${var.environment_id}-AccountService-LedgerSummary-Backup | grep -oP '(?<="BackupArn": ")[^"]*'`
     aws dynamodb restore-table-from-backup --target-table-name ${var.environment_id}-AccountService-LedgerSummary-Duplicate --backup-arn $BackupArn
    EOT
  }
}
```

This code is inside a terraform script which creates a dynamo db table, inside the provisioner I'm taking the backup of the table and trying to save that ARN into variable **BackupArn** and trying to use it in the dynamodb restore job in the second line. But it's throwing error `exit status 255. Output: 'BackupArn' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Can someone help on this? How can I get the backup ARN(if this is not the correct way) and use it in the subsequent restore command.

Comment: Which system are you running on? I'm on Linux and this works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm assuming the default interpreter is Linux in here, do I have to explicitly mention anything? @yvesonline

Comment: `local-exec` runs it on the local machine, see the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html): _This invokes a process on the machine running Terraform, not on the resource._ So check locally in a terminal if this works. If you want to run a remote command use `remote-exec`.

Comment: locally the commands are running fine for me. @yvesonline

Comment: And how are you calling Terraform?

Comment: It runs as part of a deployment azure pipeline, not something which I'm running locally @yvesonline

Comment: Then it depends what operating system your Azure pipeline runs. If the agent runs Windows or an incompatible Linux version it won't work. Check and post the Azure pipeline so that we can reproduce.

Comment: This error basically from Windows only. Please check the correct syntax for setting the command's output as a variable in Windows.

Comment: Now that I've clubbed both the commands to a single command, still getting the same issue exit status 255. Output: The system cannot find the file specified